# Using Xpath to click on link

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I seem to be having issues clicking through to the link that is in `//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]`.

I have been using the following line of code:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a[@href]"".click()
```

this is the table I wish to extract the data from

```
 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-calendar">
    <tr>
        <th width="160">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=NSW">NSW</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=VIC">VIC</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=QLD">QLD</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=WA">WA</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=SA">SA</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=TAS">TAS</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=ACT">ACT</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=NT">NT</a></th>
    </tr>  


    <tr class="rows">
        <td>
            <p><span>THURSDAY 05 JAN</span></p>
        </td>

                <td>
                    <p>

                            <a href="/FreeFields/Results.aspx?Key=2017Jan05,NSW,Taree">Taree</a><br>

                    </p>
                </td>
```

If you could help me to achieve clicking through to

```
a href="/FreeFields/Results.aspx?Key=2017Jan05,NSW,Taree
```

that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` in your code -

```
//a[contains(@href, 'Results.aspx')]
```

or

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Taree')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following `XPath`:

```
find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Taree"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below snippet of code will help you

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("url")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Taree"]').text
```